# Location service permission popup is not shown in iOS 9.1

Tags: uialertview, location-services, ios9.1

I am facing problem with iOS 9.1 when my app is installed for the first time user is prompted for location service permission, but alert view gets hidden instantly as soon as it is shown. Therefore app do not detect a user's location. Although allowing app to access location from setting.app works fine. It was working fine with iOS 9.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause for issue may be presenting a view or viewcontroller over popup.
Try to call location service permission after 1-2 second delay there may be some issue of animation that is hidding alert view.

Problem may be happening if you are asking for location service permission from appdelegate or when application is just launched else it will work fine.

Comment: Do not ever use a timed delay. All you are doing is moving a problem around. The correct solution is to to not ask from app delegate, but rather from the view controller that is launched later. You get the same behavior but the intent is clear. What if you put in a 1 second delay and then later, changed your view controller so that it launched later? The bug would re-appear.

Answer (score 0):

Now add location permission in plist file 
if not add permission in plist then permission popup is not show

Add below permission in plist

1.Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

2.Privacy - Location Always Usage Description

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with the same . I got it resolved but adding

**Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description , 
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description**

to my plist and also

You must call  **requestWhenInUseAuthorization()** method prior to using location services.